# Combining different text files in C++

Tags: c++, text-files

My fourth time on this website. Only come here because I actually have my questions answered. I have a task to combine different files (text files) together. Those files include names/grades, and I have like 12 of them. Basically I need to combine all of them into one file with  "Name" "Grade1" "Grade2" etc...
I have managed to combine a couple but I just can't wrap my head around how to find which words are used again (same names repeated several times since they appear in all 12 files) and
I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks! By the way, this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.txt");
std::ifstream file1( "Nfiles/f1.txt" ) ;
std::ifstream file2( "Nfiles/f2.txt" ) ;
std::ifstream file3( "Nfiles/f3.txt" ) ;
std::ofstream combined_file( "combined_file.txt" ) ;
combined_file << file1.rdbuf() << file2.rdbuf() << file3.rdbuf() ;
myfile.close();
return 0;
}
```

PS: Got the fstream functions from a quick search. Never knew about them till' now.

Comment: It would help to see a short example of the input files.

Comment: one solution would be to read all `Names` pass them into a vector, then use `std:unique` and `vector.erase` to remove the duplicates and write the result to a file. But it's better to show how the input files are structed internally.

Comment: By "combine" do you mean get one part from the first file, one from the second, one from the third etc., and _then_ get a _second part from the first, second, third etc. file? Because right now you just put the whole contents of the first file in the new output file, followed by the complete contents of the second, etc.

Comment: too many unknowns: is the uniqueness of the name in the lists guaranteed? are there one to one mappings for names in all lists, is one list a master?

Comment: And how would you want to handle exceptions?

Comment: No, the files all have same names and different grades. Will post an example:
"Gergo Debreczeni",7.25
"Dragolea Daniel",6.5
etc..
All files have those names and more. I need to combine them in 1 and make a list of all names and the different grade each one has.

Comment: C++ is a great language but consider a scripting language for pre-processing this, bash, perl or powershell will probably do this in less than three lines, also depending on your platform, you could use a database technology such as odbc/ado etc and use a text driver to just do sql on this

Comment: You might want to check out [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: Does not answer the question at all, but for the fun you can do it with awk `'{ g[$1] = g[$1] " " $2} END { for (x in g) print x, g[x] }' NFiles/*.txt`

Comment: I have to do this in C++. Its crucial its done in C++. I would love if someone would really shed some light on this :(

Comment: @Avraam Mavridis Yeah Avraam, that way. But, really confused on the vector.erase part :0 Could you be more specific please?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example assuming that you have two files with only the names, for something  more specific you have to saw us the structure of the input files.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>


int main(int argv,char** argc)
{


  if(argv<3)
    {
      std::cout << "Wrong input parameters" << std::endl;
      return -1;
    }

  //read two files
  std::fstream input1;
  std::fstream input2;
  input1.open(argc[1]);
  input2.open(argc[2]);

  if((!input1)||(!input2))
    {
      std::cout << "Cannot open one of the files" << std::endl;
    }


  std::istream_iterator<std::string> in1(input1);
  std::istream_iterator<std::string> in2(input2);
  std::istream_iterator<std::string> eof1;
  std::istream_iterator<std::string> eof2;


  std::vector<std::string> vector1(in1,eof1);
  std::vector<std::string> vector2(in2,eof2);

  std::vector<std::string> names;

  std::copy(vector1.begin(),vector1.end(),back_inserter(names));
  std::copy(vector2.begin(),vector2.end(),back_inserter(names));

  //std::copy(names.begin(),names.end(),std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout," "));

  std::sort(names.begin(),names.end());
  auto it=std::unique(names.begin(),names.end());

  names.erase(it);

  std::copy(names.begin(),names.end(),std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout," "));

};
```

Assuming that your file1 :

```
Paul
John
Nick
```

and your second file2:

```
Paul
Mary
Simon
```

The above code will print: `John Mary Nick Paul Simon`
It will not print `Paul` twice

Comment: Wow! I can understand half of it very well. Thanks Avraam! But let's say both files have different grades for the same people.
Like, both files have the same names but different grades. How to put those names and all of their grades on the same line as the names?

Comment: If each file have different structure the code will be far more complex and you have to specify the input parameters with specific order, `./a.out file1.txt file2.txt` maybe give different result than `./a.out file2.txt file1.txt` or maybe crash the program. It's better to import your file in an SQL database, let's say MYSQL and then use `join`. Without the specific structure of your files I can't help more :)

Comment: Here are all the files. Thanks for your great help!
http://www.putlocker.com/file/9796255695D19EC6